# How to subscribe the API fetched data in Shopware 6?

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I am a beginner to Shopware. I need to fetch data from an external API and display it in Shopware storefront. So far I have created a REST API inside the folder `Core/Api/` where I have written all the `http-client` codes to fetch data.

My route is something like this:

```
@Route("/api/v{version}/_action/rest-api-handling/test", name="api.custom.rest_api_handling.test", methods={"GET"})
```

From the documentation `https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/register-subscriber` , I need to create a subscriber to dislay data.

```
class FooterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            StorefrontRenderEvent::class => 'onFooterPageLoaded'
        ];
    }

    public function onFooterPageLoaded(StorefrontRenderEvent $event): array
    {
        return [
            "array"
        ];
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how can I call my `Route`.

Can anybody please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need the API route. First of all, API is for admin(back office app) purposes and is not for a storefront.

You need to move

> all the `http-client` codes to fetch data

to some own service. Then you can inject that new service via container to your subscriber and call something like `$this->externalApiService->getData()` in your `onFooterPageLoaded()` method.

To add some data (extend footer data) you need to add extension to pagelet e.g.

```
$event->getPagelet()->addExtension('my_data', $data);
```

Then you need to extend your twig template and access your data by

```
page.footer.extensions.my_data
```

To add array data as an extension you have to define a dummy Struct class

```
<?php

namespace MyPlugin\Struct;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Struct\Struct;

class ApiDataStruct extends Struct
{
 /**
 * @var array
 */
protected $data;

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getData(): array
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 */
public function setData(array $data): void
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

}

and then in subscriber create an instance of that object

```
$data = new ApiDataStruct();
$data->setData($this->externalApiService->getData());

$event->getPagelet()->addExtension('my_data', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried your way.  I get array at `onFooterPageLoaded()` But I am not sure how to pass this array into the view.  I can display products `$criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('product.active', true));

        $activeProducts = $this->productRepository
            ->search($criteria, $event->getContext())
            ->getEntities();

        $event->getPagelet()->addExtension('active_products', $activeProducts);` But how to display array ?

Comment: Hi @nas, i extended my answer

Comment: Hi @Valerii thanks for the updated answer. I did exactly the same where `$activeProducts` ( your answer `$data`)  $activeProduct is an array. Error is you have passed an array it should be an instance of ... Sorry I don't exactly remember error message, I am already out of my desk.

Comment: All right, yeap it should be an instance of `Shopware\Core\Framework\Struct\Struct`, so you can define dummy struct object with one field inside like `protected $data` with getter and setter. Then just create new instance and set your data array.  After that, you can add that instance as an extension to Pagelet.
Struct is DTO implementation in Shopware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227874/discussion-between-nas-and-valerii-pravoslavnyi).